# How to properly shuffle a dataset in Tensorflow after every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working on a neural network with Tensorflow and Keras, i have a dataset wrote on a TFRecord from which i have to read the data, the problem is that the neural network is trained on volumes and i dont have enough memory to store all in ram, i was reading the data like this, code taken from this 2 places:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/fast-and-lean-data-science/07_Keras_Flowers_TPU_solution.ipynb

https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/tfrecord/

```
def load_dataset(filenames):
  option_no_order = tf.data.Options()
  option_no_order.experimental_deterministic = False

  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO)
  dataset = dataset.with_options(option_no_order)
  dataset = dataset.map(decode_record, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
  return dataset

def get_batched_dataset(filenames, train=False):
dataset = load_dataset(filenames)
if train:
  dataset = dataset.repeat() # Best practices for Keras: Training dataset: repeat then batch Evaluation dataset: do not repeat
dataset = dataset.cache() # This dataset fits in RAM
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
return dataset
```

This code works, but i wanted to add the shuffling of the training dataset after every epoch and i wrote this:

```
def get_batched_dataset(filenames, train=False):
dataset = load_dataset(filenames)
if train:
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(200, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) ###############
  dataset = dataset.repeat() # Best practices for Keras: Training dataset: repeat then batch Evaluation dataset: do not repeat
dataset = dataset.cache() # This dataset fits in RAM
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO) # prefetch next batch while training (autotune prefetch buffer size)
return dataset
```

This code was working, but i was observing an augment in RAM usage after every epoch, after the 4 epoch the entire session crashed from "not enough RAM".

I get the dataset and train the network like this:

```
train_dataset = get_directories()
training_dataset = get_batched_dataset('train.tfrecords', train=True)
validation_dataset = get_batched_dataset('valid.tfrecords', train=False)
model.fit(training_dataset, steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset), epochs=80, validation_data=validation_dataset, callbacks=my_callbacks)
```

the shuffle function takes 200 of the volumes and put them in a buffer and feed them to the net randomly, i cant understand why the session crashes like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using dataset.shuffle() and then doing .cache(). Since you are changing the data order every time, tensorflow will cache every shuffled dataset in the memory. This is causing multiple shuffled copies of same dataset and RAM is getting filled.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30695038)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Custom DataGenerators](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly#data-generator).

In their `on_epoch_end` methods you can shuffle your data which will be loaded from your memory for every epoch.

Comment: thanks for the reference, i never got my hands dirty with generators, i always relied on APIs, i will give it a try, i still don't get what's the problem though